# How to conditionaly mock the response in the cypress for the same endpoint

Tags: cypress

I am writing e2e tests using cypress. I have one API endpoint, based on the request body, I will get different response. For the test I am writing, I call the API multiple times with different request body. I need to conditionally mock the response based on the request body. Here is what I have tried:

```
it("test", ()=>{
cy.intercept(
"POST", 
"https://myendpoint/GetSetting",
(req)=>{
if (req.body.contains("xyz")){
req.reply(
{
property: "xyz",
value: "certain value",
}
)
}
else req.reply()
}
cy.visit()
...
})
```

It does not seem work. I got req.body.contains is not a function. How do I check the request body or response body, based on the content, I could mock certain call(s), and let the rest calls respond as in real life? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you get in `req.body`.

Based on your mock it could be a json object with "xyz" as a property name, in which case

```js
if (req.body["xyz"]) {
```

but if the json is not yet parsed, it's a string so

```js
if (req.body.includes("xyz")) {
```

or better to parse it to make sure you check a property

```js
const parsed = JSON.parse(req.body);
if (parsed["xyz"]) {
```

Also change `else req.reply()` to `else req.continue()` otherwise you'll get undefined.

Comment: Thanks Fody. Yep that is the issue, mine is JSON object. In addition, I tried req.reply() and key.continue(), they both work with my test. Not sure what is the different between them?